# Is antivirus software necessary for Windows 10 in 2020+?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus

I use BitDefender Endpoint Protection on 200+ machines and servers. As I am about to renew the licence that is about 7000 USD / triennial, I was wondering is the antivirus necessary at all today on Windows 10?

EDIT: It said below I need to edit this question, so here gives: I am sysadmin for almost 20 years, and I need something measurable in AV protection comparison, especially from someone who is in similar position as I am. For example - if metrics say 99.4% vs 99.9% protection, that can mean much or nothing, depending on situation, so some explaining will help. The current situation is that it seems all AV programs are good, which makes the question is Windows Defender good enough from Enterprise point of view. Savings that could be made on this are huge, therefore this question must be considered. Over 6yr period AV programs costs about the same as Windows licence.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think so but this question is opinion-based anyways. Windows Defender already does a good job. The security is all in the person behind the screen, if you don't visit sketchy websites you're *mostly* fine.

Comment: Understood. Defender is a nice program, and that is why I am asking, but I am looking for solution on a large-scale basis.

Comment: @mrmut On the long-term, why you won't use Linux?

Comment: It all depends on the user - they are the weak link due to social engineering attacks. I stopped using anti-virus on my own PC about a decade ago and haven't had an infection since. Some users manage to keep infecting their PCs, regardless of what AV software they have installed. The greatest risk comes from less tech-savvy users who click on infected banner ads, download and execute malicious attachments from infected emails etc. I'd say there would be a benefit in your case as, out of 200 users, there will always be *some* who run things they shouldn't and AV will catch some of it.

Comment: Windows Defender is now good enough and is updated with Windows, so it is guaranteed of working across Windows upgrades.

Comment: We have used Symantec Endpoint on Workstations for years and we are now eliminating SEP in favour of Windows Defender because it has become an excellent product and is integrated inside Windows 10 along with EMET (which used to be standalone in earlier operating systems.

Comment: @CaldeiraG I know that you had the best of intentions with your edit, but "triennial" wasn't actually a typo.

Comment: Although there is no absolute authority on antivirus testing, this one has always been well-regarded. Defender was doing better & better over the past few years, until this year, when it's fallen down the rankings a long way [for both business & home] See https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/business-windows-client/

Comment: @Run5k my bad. Never heard the word before and didn't bother to search it :\

Comment: @Tetsujin I just checked, and it seems all producers fluctuate a bit. Last month Defender had top score with many others. This month 5.5. Few months ago it was close to the top. I am only not sure how often it updates - if it goes thru Windows update, that might be a bit unreliable on some machines. The other Q is availability of monitoring console.

Comment: @Tetsujin The only place Windows Defender fell was in performance, which is where the 5.5 comes from... detection was 100%.  For the last few years, Windows Defender has consistently scored as one of the best antivirus programs across multiple independent tests to the point where it's become pointless for 3rd party antivirus if running Windows 10.

Comment: @mrmut Provided Controlled Folder Access is enabled in Windows Defender (Ransomeware protection), there's little point to running a 3rd party antivirus on Win10.  Money like that would be better spent on a UTM router OS that's able to detect and quarantine any machines found to be infected with malware from accessing any other machines on the network _([Sophos UTM](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/unified-threat-management.aspx) for instance, which is offered as both a hardware appliance, as well as a standalone software appliance)_

Comment: @JW0914 - no, it fell in protection, not performance. It scores nowhere near as well as it did last year.  Though all products fluctuate a bit, you have to watch the overall trend over a long time to really get a feel for it. I'd agree with you on the UTM front though. I have Sophos UTM here.

Comment: I think it is a good idea to consider the value of the extra features that "endpoint" anti-virus provides for sysadmins. Features like remote administration, "deep-freeze", reporting user activity, etc. AFAIK Windows Defender can be remotely configured by a Group Policy, but beyond that there is really no features that help sysadmins manage or monitor the security of multiple PCs. Even Microsoft wants to sell those features separately.

Comment: @kenorb Actually I use UNIX (macOS). Linux is also a nice choice, but all of the business applications are on Windows, and most importantly - people know how to and want to work on Windows. Transition to Win 10 was a horror for some, so imagine switch to Linux. Plus, Windows is actually a good platform for mass management with group policies and central and reliable account management.

Comment: @Romen You might be right. I really like the online console  and reporting. - Just spoke with a colleague from another company, and he is categorically for the dedicated solution. The main issue by him is update frequency and cloud management. The bad thing here is that I don't have metric to compare the two. - If the work hours of fixing stuff that Windows Defender would pass through are too high, then the toning down wouldn't pay.